# What is the meaning of N(N) in this common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I saw this csv parser function [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), I was wondering what is the meaning of N(N) in thie cte1

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfParse] (@String varchar(max))
Returns Table 
As

Return (  

    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+1 From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,1) = ','),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(',',@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A where LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L))) <> ''
);
```

Comment: `A.N, A.L` is a particularly unfortunate confluence of names... maybe that's just me, but I'd be doing some renaming anyway. If a name is not necessary to the rest of the query but syntactically required, I prefer to use `_`, `__`, `___` and so on to make this clear, so that's what I'd rename the `N` table to.

Answer (score 1):

You could write `A(B)` as well. `A` is the alias of the subquery, `B` is the alias of the returned column from the subquery (`Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)`).

Comment: is the N(N) even necessary in cte1?

Comment: @mohas - the names are *irrelevant* to the rest of the query but required. (Since the CTE has an explicit column list, that's where it takes its column names from)

Answer (score 1):

A values statement in the `from` clause creates a derived table with no name and whose columns have no name.

The `as N(N)` is giving them names, `N` for the table and `N` for the column.

These are all equivalent:

```
select n.n from (Values (1), (1)) N(N)

select 1 from (Values (1), (1)) N(N)

select 1 as n from (Values (1), (1)) a(b)

select a.b as n from (Values (1), (1)) a(b)
```